# How do I transfer an expiring domain to a different person?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

A while ago, me and a friend created a website together and he handled all the domain registration (with GoDaddy). Now, the domain registration is about to expire (in 2 weeks time) but my friend is not interested in working on the website and renewing the domain anymore. As a complete webmaster noob, my two biggest questions are:

- Is there a way for him to transfer the domain so that for now on I am the one in charge of it and I am the one responsible for renewing it? In particular, is there are difference between a trusted friend transferring the domain and arranging a transfer with a stranger?
- Do I need to keep using the same domain registrar or can I switch to another one? I don't really understand what would be the difference between them and I am confused because everything I searched for assumes that I already own the domain.

I don't mind if the whole process takes a while to complete as the website is currently off the air anyways. My priority is keeping the domain name in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest course of action for you would be to create a new account at the same registrar (GoDaddy) and use their internal "Change of Account".

The steps are:

1. You sign up for a new GoDaddy account
2. You give your account number to your friend
3. Your friend [initiates an account change for the domain](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/822/moving-a-domain-name-out-of-your-account) (link is to detailed instruction for your friend)
4. You [accept the domain name into your account](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1670/accepting-a-domain-name-into-your-account?locale=en) (link is to detailed instructions for you)

An internal change of account can be completed the same day (and must be completed within 10 days).    Transferring to another registrar can take much longer.

Comment: And the idea is that after he transfers it to me I would immediately renew it and then worry about changing registrars latter on right?

Comment: Correct.   Although there is no *need* to change registrars.   You can change hosting providers while still having the domain registered at GoDaddy.

Answer (score 4):

If you are transferring the domain to another Hosting Company, you would need to ask for the EPP Authorization Code from your current registrar and give it to your new Registrar (Most Web Hosting Companies resell domains). They will then send you an email to verify that you are indeed transferring it, and after you click the link it will take 5-7 days for the domain to transfer in most cases. If they are reselling the domains through the same registrar (for example, ENOM), they may be able to 'push' the domain through faster.

I hope this helps.